# How to disable/allow SSL for my PEM server installation through Stack Builder?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I installed Postgres v13.11 (x64). After its installation, I opted to install additional services through Stack Builder (PEM Server v9, PEM Agent v9, PEM-HTTPD v2.
Stack Builder then started installing PEM Server however when prompted to enter in PEM Server installation details, I get the following error:
['psql: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNMfr.png)

I've looked at other similar questions and possible solutions online but they all seem to be encountering this error (and subsequently fixing it) while using the psql shell and either setting sslmode to allow or disable as such:

```
psql "sslmode=disable host=localhost dbname=test"
```

or

```
psql "sslmode=allow host=localhost dbname=test"
```

Im not sure how to use these fixes for an installation through Stack Builder.

Comment: I have no idea what a PEM server is, but maybe you should enable SSL by setting `ssl = on` in PostgreSQL and providing a certificate and private key, as described in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssl-tcp.html).